# Regular Expression: Match until pattern is found

Tags: .net, regex

I want to extract the status from the string untill I found a timespan. My input is something like "Something in start but not with this keyword of sure. STATUS: My Status Is Here Which can be anything but timespan 23:59:01 and so on. I want to extract the string after **STATUS:** untill **23:59:01** is found. How can i achieve this through regex. this **23:59:01** is a timespan and it is always in this format **hh:mm:ss**

Comment: What language are you using? Always include this in regex questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your specification is rather unclear, but you can try `STATUS: (.*?) \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`; this captures the portion that you want into group 1.

You may want to enable singleline if the `.` is to also match newline.

#### See also

- [Above regex in action on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/aveMdyRa9U)

  - (we can go back and forth on rubular if you need the pattern fine tuned further)

---

In C#, you'd write something like this ([see it on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/5cBhu)):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"STATUS: (.*?) \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (Match match in r.Matches(text)) {
  Console.WriteLine("[[[" + match.Groups[1] + "]]]");
}
```

The `RegexOptions.Singleline` allows `.` to match any character, so it works when the desired string contains newlines.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

---

#### Why reluctant?

That's just in case you need multiple matches (as shown above). In the example below, there is only one `A.*Z` (with greedy).

```
---A--Z----A----Z---
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       A.*Z
```

Comment: What language are you using? I am using .net
polygenelubricants I think you got what i want but your provided regex is not working. Another thing i want to add is my status can be on multiple line. To further clear my requirements. I need to extract any thing between STATUS: and \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
STATUS:[\sa-zA-Z]+?[:\d]{8}
```